# Order by group sum

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

take a diamond data set in ggplot as an example I want to order the data frame by the total price for each color , so if for example this is the total price for each color

```
H        5000
I        4000    
E        1000
J        3000
```

I want to sort the original data frame to display colors in the same order above

so if we have a sample from original data set like this

```
carat   cut        color    clarity depth   table   price
0.23    Ideal        E        SI2   61.5    55       326
0.21    Premium      E        SI1   59.8    61       326
0.23    Good         E        VS1   56.9    65       327
0.29    Premium      I        VS2   62.4    58       334
0.31    Good         J        SI2   63.3    58       335
0.24    Very Good    J        VVS2  62.8    57       336
0.24    Very Good    I        VVS1  62.3    57       336
0.26    Very Good    H         SI1  61.9    55       337
```

it should be sorted to be something like this

```
carat   cut        color    clarity depth   table   price
0.26    Very Good    H        SI1   61.9    55       337    
0.24    Very Good    I        VVS1  62.3    57       336
0.29    Premium      I        VS2   62.4    58       334
0.23    Ideal        E        SI2   61.5    55       326
0.21    Premium      E        SI1   59.8    61       326
0.23    Good         E        VS1   56.9    65       327
0.31    Good         J        SI2   63.3    58       335
0.24    Very Good    J        VVS2  62.8    57       336
```

because H color has the highest total price and then I and so on.

I can order the color by total price for each color , but I want to order the 
data set itself by color

as mentioned above .

and it will be better that we can do another ordering for by price for each record so it will be something like this

```
carat   cut        color    clarity depth   table   price
0.26    Very Good    H        SI1   61.9    55       337    
0.24    Very Good    I        VVS1  62.3    57       336
0.29    Premium      I        VS2   62.4    58       334
0.23    Good         E        VS1   56.9    65       327    
0.23    Ideal        E        SI2   61.5    55       326
0.21    Premium      E        SI1   59.8    61       326    
0.24    Very Good    J        VVS2  62.8    57       336    
0.31    Good         J        SI2   63.3    58       335
```

Comment: Your desired output is a bit confusing because it doesn't match the description. Color `E` should be first, etc.

Comment: this is a sample from data not the actual data

Comment: I get that, but your desired output should correspond to the sample data in order avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table` I would do the following (using the data provided by you)

```
library(data.table)
# convert to `data.table` and assign a TotSum column (per color) by reference
setDT(df)[, TotSum := sum(price), by = color]
# sort your data by total sum (decreasing), color (in case two colors will have the same total price) and by price (decreasing)
setorder(df, -TotSum, color, -price) 
df
#    carat       cut color clarity depth table price TotSum
# 1:  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327    979
# 2:  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326    979
# 3:  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326    979
# 4:  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336    671
# 5:  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335    671
# 6:  0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336    670
# 7:  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334    670
# 8:  0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337    337
```

Here we created a new column of `TotSum` per color and the ordered `df` *by reference* by the total sum, color, and the price within each color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the ordering that you want, but if it is first by price and then by color, both in descending order, then you can do:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')
tst <- dplyr::arrange(diamonds, desc(color), desc(price))
```

Which gives, for `head(tst)`:

```
  carat     cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  3.01 Premium     J     SI2  60.7    59 18710 9.35 9.22 5.64
2  3.01 Premium     J     SI2  59.7    58 18710 9.41 9.32 5.59
3  2.22 Premium     J     VS1  60.0    60 18706 8.49 8.43 5.08
4  3.51 Premium     J     VS2  62.5    59 18701 9.66 9.63 6.03
5  2.43 Premium     J     VS2  62.2    57 18692 8.63 8.54 5.34
6  2.42 Premium     J     VS2  61.3    59 18615 8.61 8.58 5.27
```

Comment: Where's the total price per color element?

Comment: Well, the first part of the question seemed rather different from the next part (the last 3 illustrations) so I wasn't certain what the question was!  None of the last examples involve total price.  Your mind-reading skills are better than mine.